# Conditionally remove items from a list in R

Tags: r

I know there are many similar questions about removing items from a list, but I've been unable to solve my problem in particular - and I appreciate the help.

Simply put, I'd like to remove any entry (row) that has a value that is greater than `-74`.

```
list(structure(c(40.7571907043457, 40.7601699829102, 40.761848449707, 
40.7660789489746, -73.9972381591797, -74.0038146972656, -74.0072479248047, 
-74.0172576904297), .Dim = c(4L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), c("lat", "lon"))), structure(c(40.7582893371582, 
40.760498046875, 40.7620582580566, 40.7662887573242, -73.9975280761719, 
-74.0031967163086, -74.0070190429688, -74.0170593261719), .Dim = c(4L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4"), c("lat", "lon"))))
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you only looking for `lon` column? If so then simply  `lapply(your_list, function(i)i[i[,2] <= -74,])`

Comment: Thanks @Sotos ! Where can I learn more about the syntax used here?

Comment: [Here](http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/index.html#introduction) is a great book to get you started

Comment: Thanks again @Sotos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to look at `lon` column with the negative values then simply,

```
lapply(your_list, function(i)i[i[,2] <= -74,])
```

In case you want to check both columns,

```
lapply(your_list, function(i)i[rowSums(i<=-74) > 0, , drop = FALSE])
```

Both give the same result,

> ```
> [[1]]
>        lat       lon
> 2 40.76017 -74.00381
> 3 40.76185 -74.00725
> 4 40.76608 -74.01726
>
> [[2]]
>        lat       lon
> 2 40.76050 -74.00320
> 3 40.76206 -74.00702
> 4 40.76629 -74.01706
> ```